# BETWEEN two dates query

Tags: sql-server, between

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

I have a table called Books:

```
BookID
BookName
BookStatus
LoanDate
ReturnDate
```

I want to return the `BookName` values within a range using BETWEEN.

Here's the catch:

- When the `BookStatus` is 'Loaned' use `LoanDate` in the BETWEEN statement.
- When the `BookStatus` is 'Returned' use `ReturnDate` in the BETWEEN statement.

Code:

```
SELECT BookName 
FROM Books 
  WHEN LoanDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '10/01/2014' AND BookStatus = 'Loaned'

SELECT BookName 
FROM Books 
   WHEN ReturnDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '10/01/2014' AND BookStatus = 'Returned'
```

How to merge those queries into one?

Comment: You're almost there. Put a `UNION ALL` between them, and change WHEN to `WHERE`

Comment: I think you meant to use `WHERE` instead of `WHEN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use a `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT BookName 
FROM Books 
WHERE LoanDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '10/01/2014' AND BookStatus='Loaned'

UNION ALL

SELECT BookName 
FROM Books 
WHERE ReturnDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '10/01/2014' AND BookStatus='Returned'
```

Or use `OR` and concatenate the two queries into one.

```
SELECT BookName 
FROM Books 
WHERE (LoanDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '10/01/2014' AND BookStatus='Loaned')
OR (ReturnDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '10/01/2014' AND BookStatus='Returned')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OR

```
SELECT BookName FROM Books 
WHERE (LoanDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '10/01/2014' AND BookStatus='Loaned') 
OR (ReturnDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '10/01/2014' AND BookStatus='Returned')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT BookName 
FROM Books 
WHERE LoanDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '10/01/2014' 
AND BookStatus='Loaned'

UNION ALL

SELECT BookName 
FROM Books 
WHERE ReturnDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '10/01/2014' 
AND BookStatus='Returned'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the CASE or the OR statement (they will have the same execution plan), a UNION ALL is twice as costly.

```
--Query cost 25%
SELECT * FROM Books WHERE 
(BookStatus = 'Loaned' AND LoanDate  BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '10/01/2014')
OR
(BookStatus = 'Returned' AND ReturnDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '10/01/2014')

--Query cost 25%
SELECT * FROM Books WHERE 
CASE    WHEN BookStatus = 'Loaned' THEN LoanDate  
        WHEN BookStatus = 'Returned' THEN ReturnDate END 
        BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '10/01/2014'

--Query cost 50%
SELECT * FROM Books WHERE BookStatus = 'Loaned' AND LoanDate  BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '10/01/2014'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Books WHERE BookStatus = 'Returned' AND ReturnDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '10/01/2014'
```